# How to weight `on_initialize`?

Tags: storage, benchmarking, weight, benchmark, rocks-db

Is there any best practice how to count the weights in `on_initialize` correctly?

I read through the Polkadot and Substrate `on_initialize` weight calculations and couldn't always figure out: When to benchmark? When to use benchmark components? When to use manual read and write additions?

---

Just an example [here](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/f000f3a992a1f0ae043feeb27b50751d4d124930/runtime/common/src/slots/mod.rs#L229-L304). There the length of `Leases` was not taken into account of the weight benchmark.

---

In regards to benchmark components: Why does the component `MaxApprovals` affect the weight [here](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/28f0cb18c96fb82f810f1d9be69fb609fbb7217e/frame/treasury/src/lib.rs#L388-L409)?

---

Why do we return 0 weight [here](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/28f0cb18c96fb82f810f1d9be69fb609fbb7217e/frame/treasury/src/lib.rs#L317-L324), when there was at least the calculation of `(n % T::SpendPeriod::get()).is_zero()` (which also should consume a little bit processing time)?

---

[This](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/28f0cb18c96fb82f810f1d9be69fb609fbb7217e/frame/treasury/src/lib.rs#L511-L544) is a pretty good example, that the length of `Approvals` affect the weight and should be a component.

---

[Here](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/96596bcaac7d1fd60cf0e4f066ebf8ba3b810d84/frame/aura/src/lib.rs#L89-L112) only `T::DbWeight::get().` is used. But isn't there some processing time for the `assert` call? Why wasn't benchmarking taken into account there? When using this style. Why couldn't I just use `T::DbWeight::get().reads_writes(proposals_approvals_len, proposals_approvals_len)` [here](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/28f0cb18c96fb82f810f1d9be69fb609fbb7217e/frame/treasury/src/lib.rs#L511-L542)?

---

I count the following `reads_writes` in `on_initialize` and `on_finalize` [here](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/a1a9b475c354d873f91135ed5fa028ac9ef6a2c4/frame/transaction-storage/src/lib.rs#L149-L180):

READS:
`StoragePeriod`, `ChunkCount`, `ProofChecked` ([take](https://crates.parity.io/frame_support/storage/types/struct.StorageValue.html#method.take)), `BlockTransactions`

WRITES:
`Transactions`, `ChunkCount`, `ProofChecked` ([take](https://crates.parity.io/frame_support/storage/types/struct.StorageValue.html#method.take)), `BlockTransactions`

But it is `T::DbWeight::get().reads_writes(2, 4)`, why?

---

I would expect `T::DbWeight::get().writes(1)` [here](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/f000f3a992a1f0ae043feeb27b50751d4d124930/xcm/pallet-xcm/src/lib.rs#L412). Why it only takes the weight of `check_xcm_version_change` into the overall weight?

---

Can you provide any best practices how to correctly count the weights of `on_initialize`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will try to answer most of the Qs.

> When to benchmark? When to use manual read and write additions?

The short answer: use benchmarks and not manual guesstimates for hooks' weights.
I can't really justify the practice since its error-prone and breaks easily.

> When to use benchmark components?

I think your observations are correct. Benchmarking components should be used when the weight has a dependency on the size or length of a specific value.
There are obviously bugs in the code; developers don't always take all variables into account or a later amendment invalidates it.

One exception exists for storage. The storage weights are benchmarked with a [full snapshot](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/c3d5882a64e5330a04d9b2486891e30ac9c58768/runtime/polkadot/constants/src/weights/paritydb_weights.rs#L22) and therefore always worst case. So you don't have to populate all maps every time you write a benchmark.

> Why do we return 0 weight here, when there was at least the calculation of (n % T::SpendPeriod::get()).is_zero() (which also should consume a little bit processing time)?

Yes ideally this should have a benchmark. The effort for this is currently ignored.
The `scheduler` pallet has a lot of `on_initialize` benchmarks if you need inspiration.

> Can you provide any best practices how to correctly count the weights of `on_initialize`?

Best not to do it.
Anyway, a relay chain will not really suffer from slightly incorrect weights since its blocks always execute. Sure there could be longer block times, but then it can be fixed.
For a para-chain this is not a good idea, since a grossly overweight `on_initialize` could lead collators to miss their block production slot and stall the chain.

I will go through your posted cases and open an issue (link: TBD).

Comment: Are the storage weights also benchmarked in a snapshot for a parachain? So do I need as parachain developer need to think about the weight of a child tree access for example? According to this https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/issues/5928

Comment: Parachains should benchmark their own storage weights instead of using the Polkadot defaults, yet. The procedure is not nicely explained yet, but most is covered [here](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/utils/frame/benchmarking-cli/src/storage/README.md). Related issue: [#12081](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/issues/12081). The weights are defined [here](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/157a123d05bb3548c042f91430f65de5a6e51d7e/runtime/polkadot/constants/src/weights/rocksdb_weights.rs#L59).